# For my login page i have a picture as its background. But once you login it transfers over to the game as well blocking it

Tags: html, css

[This image has my code and the picture of the homepage to the website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZEow.jpg)
The actual site has a picture background and it transfers over to the game after logging in. In the body is where I did the background

How can i fix it where the picture goes away after logging in?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div id="signDiv" class ="textbox">
 <h1> Login</h1>
 Username: <input id="signDiv-username" type="text"></input><br>
 Password: <input id="signDiv-password" type="password"></input>
 <button id="signDiv-signIn" class="btn">Sign In</button>
 <button id="signDiv-signUp" class="btn">Sign Up</button>
 <style>
  body{
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   font-family: sans-serif;
   background: url(tank.jpg) no-repeat;
   background-size: cover;
   background-position: center;
   height:100vh;
```

Comment: Please paste the code and conditions as a working examples for us to have a look. Thanks

Comment: i pasted the code used in the body is this what u meant? The image has the rest of it and what the actual site looks like. If you need the rest of the code ill also paste it in.

Answer (score 1):

dont use the `body` to define something, thus, you will set something for all your pages, use a class for fix it

```
body.login {
    background-color: red;
}

body.islogged {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

you need set a class in the body for each page, so each page will have a behavior.

```
<body class="login">
</body>
```

this body will have background red in my sample

Comment: you can also set another things based on that, for example
`body.login input {
    border: none;
}`
in this case all inputs in login page will have nene border...
You can also use ID instead class:
`body#login{

}`